# How do I display the data fetched from called view controller into a dynamic tableviewcell of the calling view controller while using unwind segue.?

Tags: swift

I have dynamic tableview, wherein one of the cell (duration) when tapped opens another view controller which is a list of duration viz (30 min, 1 hour, 2 hours and so fort). One of the durations when selected should display the selected duration in the first view controller. I am able to pass the data back to first view controller using unwind segue but unable to display the passed value. DOn't know whats missing.
I am displaying the code below:
FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER (CALLING)

```
@IBAction func unwindWithSelectedDuration(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("durationCell") as! durationTableViewCell
    if let durationTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? DurationTableViewController,
        selectedDuration = durationTableViewController.selectedDuration {
            cell.meetingDurationCell.text = selectedDuration
            duration = selectedDuration
    }
```

SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER (CALLED)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SaveSelectedDuration" {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            if let index = indexPath?.row {
                selectedDuration = durationList[index]

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` should only be called within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It has no use outside this context.

The easiest fix is to just reload the table once you have stored the selected duration:

```
@IBAction func unwindWithSelectedDuration(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let durationTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? DurationTableViewController {
        selectedDuration = durationTableViewController.selectedDuration
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes you only need one `selectedDuration` for your whole table, rather than one per row. If you need one per row, I assume you have them stored in an array somewhere, so it is that array that should be updated instead before the `reloadData`.